# Inconsistency in adding Gen 1:31 to Gen 2:1-3 on Friday Nights

Tags: tefilla, kiddush

We say Gen 2:1-3 three times each Friday evening, once in the Amida, once after the Amida and once in the Fri Night Kiddush (Vayachulu hashamaim vehaaretz vechol tzvaam).  Only one time do we preface this with a few words from Gen 1:31 (Vayehi erev vayehi Boker yom hashishi).

Why the inconsistency?

Comment: It might have something special to do with kiddush, the number of words, and some kabbalistic intentions (that I don't understand) that are specifically about kiddush. See (the original source?) [Sha'ar HaKavanot](https://www.sefaria.org/Sha'ar_HaKavanot%2C_Sermons_on_Sabbath_Night_Kiddush.1.1.6?vhe=Shaar_HaKavanot&lang=he).